# Apple Mach-O Linked Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hi i all i found a lot of answer but didn't get the solution. Here i am posting my error that i am getting. Please help me get rid of this.

```
Ld /Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.app/JEDI normal i386
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bsharp/sites/default/iOS_Development/JEDI
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/JEDI.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/JEDI_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.app/JEDI

duplicate symbol _IS_ALREADY_LOGIN in:
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/CustomCell.o
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _TRUE_CHECK in:
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/CustomCell.o
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _FONT_NAME in:
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/CustomCell.o
/Users/Rupesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JEDI-fptiyjulpownybgfqknfffphqrvl/Build/Intermediates/JEDI.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/JEDI.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project contains duplicate symbols which means you're trying to compile two identical files which contain the implementation for the same class. Check your project files and eliminate any duplicate .m files (like CustomCell and ViewController)

Maybe _IS_ALREADY_LOGIN, _TRUE_CHECK etc is defined more than once in CustomCell.h/m and ViewController.h/m?

Comment: Thanks for response but in my project only one file is there of ViewController and CustomCell.